# Ordering data frame column by desc causing Analysis exception [Pyspark]

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a data frame with 3 columns: journal, abstract, and word count. I'm trying to calculate the average word count of the abstract for each journal and then order them in descending order to show the journals with the longest average abstract.

I've managed to get to a point where I have just the journal and average word count. That was done by doing:

```
newDF = marchDF.select("journal", "abstract").withColumn("wordcount", lit("0").cast("integer")).withColumn("wordcount", sql.size(sql.split(sql.col("abstract"), " ")))
nonullDF = newDF.filter(col("journal").isNotNull()).filter(col("abstract").isNotNull())
groupedDF = nonullDF.select("journal", "wordcount").groupBy("journal").avg("wordcount")
```

however, when I try to order it by wordcount, it throws the error:

> cannot resolve '`wordcount`' given input columns: [avg(wordcount), journal];;

I've tried:

```
orderedDF = groupedDF.orderBy(col("wordcount")).desc().show(5)
```

and:

```
orderedDF = groupedDF.sort(col("wordcount")).desc.show(5)
```

but both throw that same error and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because as the error says, there is no column named `wordcount`. The column you want to order by is called `avg(wordcount)`, so you can do

```
orderedDF = groupedDF.orderBy("avg(wordcount)", ascending=False).show(5)
```

Alternatively, you can rename the `avg` column to `wordcount` during the aggregation:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

groupedDF = nonullDF.select("journal", "wordcount").groupBy("journal").agg(F.avg("wordcount").alias("wordcount"))
orderedDF = groupedDF.orderBy("wordcount", ascending=False).show(5)
```

Note also the correct syntax for ordering in descending order.